# Flash not using PulseAudio

Tags: flash, pulseaudio, gstreamer, pavucontrol

I'm using gstreamer with pavucontrol. When I go to www.google.com and press the 'voice search' button in either Firefox or Chrome gstreamer reports a recording device named "Chrome/Firefox ALSA."

Whenever Flash is used, on the other hand, no recording device is present. My microphone will work fine, but no recording device is shown in pavucontrol. This is baffling. Do you have an ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Flash does not use Pulseaudio, this is a [known issue](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2968177). PulseAudio developers need to rely on Adobe's support to fix this.